# How to change default systemdate from ymd to dmy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Can somebody help me to change the default systemdate from ymd to dmy? These must be for always the default format !! How?

Comment: If you can avoid representing date(time)s as strings, strive to do so. If you must use a string, use an unambiguous format, and that way it doesn't matter what server settings are in force. `'20110519'` is unambiguous. As is `'2011-05-19T07:50:23'`.

Answer (score 10):

[SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx):

> Sets the order of the month, day, and
>   year date parts for interpreting date,
>   smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2 and
>   datetimeoffset character strings.

[Note: This is often not the way to solve the problem of interpreting dates.  Datetimes should not be stored a strings if you can avoid it (use a datetime or date column instead). If you have to store in a string form, use an ISO 8601 format which is basically of the form YYYYMMDD ]

Example from MSDN:

```
-- Set date format to day/month/year.
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
GO
DECLARE @datevar datetime2 = '31/12/2008 09:01:01.1234567';
SELECT @datevar;
GO
-- Result: 2008-12-31 09:01:01.123
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
GO
DECLARE @datevar datetime2 = '12/31/2008 09:01:01.1234567';
SELECT @datevar;
GO
-- Result: Msg 241: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time -- from character string.
GO
```

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to set the default date format for the current login by changing the default language.

For month/day/year:

```
ALTER LOGIN [MyUser] WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = us_english
select CAST('01-06-2011' as datetime)
-- 2011-01-06 00:00:00.000
```

Or for day/month/year:

```
ALTER LOGIN [MyUser] WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = British
select CAST('01-06-2011' as datetime)
-- 2011-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

You can choose from any of the languages listed in `sys.syslanguages`.  Changes won't take effect until you login again.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

GO

RECONFIGURE

GO

DBCC USEROPTIONS

SELECT GETDATE()
```