# Insert time in time(7) data type SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, time

I can't insert a value for a `TIME(7)` column in SQL Server :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vuelos] ([fechaSalida], [horasalida], [fechaLlegada], [horaLlegada],
                            [id_avion], [idAereopuertoOrigen],[idAereopuertoDestino], [estado])
 VALUES (12-03-2019, 12:03:20, 14-4-2019, 03:12:33,
         3, 2, 3, 'Disponible')
```

I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near ':'.

on the first date line

The table structure is:

```
       (<fechaSalida, date,>
       ,<horasalida, time(7),>
       ,<fechaLlegada, date,>
       ,<horaLlegada, time(7),>
       ,<id_avion, int,>
       ,<idAereopuertoOrigen, int,>
       ,<idAereopuertoDestino, int,>
       ,<estado, varchar(50),>)
```

Comment: Try putting your date and time values in single quotes. so your value 12-03-2019 becomes '12-03-2019' and 12:03:20 becomes '12:03:20'

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: It is safest to enter dates literals in YYYY-MM-DD format, as that is unambiguous. Try changing the dates to '2019-03-12' and '2019-04-14'

Comment: the error is the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your date and time values within quotes to make them strings.

```
 VALUES
       ('12-03-2019'
       ,'12:03:20'
       ,'14-4-2019'
       ,'03:12:33'
```

Without the quotes, they are treated as plain numerical expressions.  12-03-2019 is interpreted as 12 subtract 3 subtract 2019.  Then the parser gets confused when it reaches the colon in 12:03:20.

Answer (score 0):

try inserting values with quotes. Also, if you trying to insert the date in dd/mm/yyyy format then you need to provide the hint to the SQL server engine.

DATEFORMAT allows us to insert Date in the desired format.
different date format options are:

1. DMY – dd/MM/yyyy. e.g. 12/04/2018.
2. YDM – yyyy/dd/MM. e.g. 2018/12/04.
3. MDY – MM/dd/yyyy. e.g. 04/14/2018.
4. YMD – yyyy/MM/dd. e.g. 2018/04/14.

[See More Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054794/how-to-change-default-systemdate-from-ymd-to-dmy)

```
    SET DATEFORMAT DMY INSERT INTO [dbo].[Vuelos]
       ([fechaSalida]
       ,[horasalida]
       ,[fechaLlegada]
       ,[horaLlegada]
       ,[id_avion]
       ,[idAereopuertoOrigen]
       ,[idAereopuertoDestino]
       ,[estado]) VALUES
       (
       '12-03-2019'
       ,'12:03:20'
       ,'14-4-2019'
       ,'03:12:33'
       ,3
       ,2
       ,3
       , 'Disponible')
```

[image: Record after insert]

Comment: THIS SAVE ME, I LOVE YOU, butt... i dont get why this worked and when i tried with the quotes it didnt work

Comment: Maybe you didn't set the DATFORMAT then.

Comment: if i set 12-03-2019 in table it display 12/3/2019 is posible add the zero in the month?

Comment: Where are you seeing 12/3/2019, after inserting the records it looks like the image which I added to the answer. I didn't get your point.

Comment: Sorry, the table is correct, i get confused with the data that i get in a vb program that im making, when i run the sql command my table gets that date without the zero