# How to find difference in days from DD-MM-YYYY formatted dates in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to find the difference between two dates in `DD-MM-YYYY` format. For example, I have 2 dates `29-10-2018` and `29-11-2018`. I want to find the difference in number of days between those two dates (30 days) in SQL Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116540/difference-of-two-date-time-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference of two date time in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116540/difference-of-two-date-time-in-sql-server)

Comment: When you say *dates in DD-MM-YYYY format* do you mean they are being stored as a 'string' type (e.g. Varchar?)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `date format` of current session and then use `DateDiff` function.

```
SET DATEFORMAT 'dmy'

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '29-10-2018', '29-11-2018')
```

I will check more about `Set DateFormat` before adding this to Production code.

That changes the SESSION date format, not the DATABASE.

[Note from [Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054794/how-to-change-default-systemdate-from-ymd-to-dmy): This is often not the way to solve the problem of interpreting dates. Datetimes should not be stored a strings if you can avoid it (use a datetime or date column instead). If you have to store in a string form, use an ISO 8601 format which is basically of the form YYYYMMDD]

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEDIFF

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF(day, '2018-10-29 00:00:00.000', '2010-11-29 00:00:00.000')
```

Answer (score 0):

---

declare @date1 varchar(10),@date2 varchar(10)

set @date1 = '01-11-2018'

set @date2 = '28-11-2018'

select

```
        datefromparts(
                      right(left(@date2 ,10),4),
                      substring(left(@date2 ,10),4,2),
                      left(left(@date2 ,10),2)
                      )
```

select
        DATEDIFF
                (
                    DAY,

```
                datefromparts( right(left(@date1 ,10),4),

                       substring(left(@date1 ,10),4,2),

                       left(left(@date1 ,10),2)

                     ),

        datefromparts( right(left(@date2 ,10),4),

            substring(left(@date2 ,10),4,2),

            left(left(@date2 ,10),2)

            )

    )
```

---